# 1980s series where a humanoid people transform during adolescence

Tags: story-identification, books

Does anyone recall reading a book series (there may have only been two) where a human finds themselves in a world where the human-like creatures go through a complicated transformation during adolescence that I believe was called the awakening. (It's also possible that the point of view character wasn't a human, but a lost individual of the same race that is rediscovering their origins.)

From what I recall, the creatures had tails and were quite fantastical, but not serpent like--more mystical. There were complex and vivid descriptions of the physical transformations (with imagery like flowers blooming) and some sort of magical ceremony that occurred when the person reached adolescence. There were definite sensual undertones and possibly a homosexual theme.

Comment: You've provided uniquely identifying details which is a good start. Can I suggest you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: Did they grow wings during the transformation? I vaguely remember a book with "darkling" or "darkwing" in the title.  Key element was the wings appeared on the back as blisters and had to be cut open to be released.

Comment: That does sound familiar. I added some more details to the original post.

Comment: Could this be the Wraethtu trilogy by Storm Constantine? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wraeththu

Comment: @sueelleker: My thought too, but the Wraethtu don't have tails, I think.